# Javascript conditional postback on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a button control in my ASP.NET page which should conditionally postback based on some criteria.

```
<input runat="server" type="button" id="btnDone" value="Select" onclick="return SendAndCloseAdvWin();" onserverclick="serverProcessing" />
```

.

```
function SendAndCloseAdvWin() {
  var win = GetRadWindow();

  if (GetRadCtrl('lstSelectors').get_checkedItems().length == 0) {
    DisplayError('Please select atleast one item.');

    return false;
  }
  else {
    if (win) {
      win.close(GetSelectedItems());
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

If the condition is true the page should not postback, else it should postback. But i find that even if the condition fails the page does not postback. Am i missing somwething here?

Comment: how are you calling this function??

Comment: like this onclick="return SendAndCloseAdvWin();"

Comment: Is `GetRadWindow` returning anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is a 'Button' not a 'Submit' button.

Try changing your button to:

```
<input runat="server" type="submit" id="btnDone" value="Select" onclick="return SendAndCloseAdvWin();" onserverclick="serverProcessing" />
```

Also in your JS, you don't return any value in your 'else', unless the nested condition is met. You should return true/false in the fall-through.

```
  else {
    if (win) {
      win.close(GetSelectedItems());
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```